# How Scanner's nextLine() method stops execution on pressing return key?

Tags: java, multithreading

I was breaking some ice with Threads but I got stuck because on

> pressing **RETURN key** thread ends

but on `typing some string` thread `didn't stop`. Why is that because `nexLine()` method takes any string value and why on pressing RETURN key thread stops?

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
    private boolean running = true;

    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            System.out.println("hello");
        }
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        running = false;
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyThread obj = new MyThread();
        obj.start();

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        input.nextLine();    
        obj.shutdown();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the thread will die when the run method returns, and this will happen when `nextLine` returns which will happen when a line break occurs.

From `Scanner.nextLine() Docs`.

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that
>   was skipped.

Answer (score 1):

It stops the moment it hits the end of the line. Entering "enter" is the same as it hitting "\n" thus stopping. Reading the documentation on the method and Scanner class might help further understand it.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: then why didnt it ends when I enter some **string** ?